# Tool that can do semantic search in a body of C code

Tags: c

I'm looking for a tool that can do semantic search in a body of C code.
Example query: "give me all references to field y in struct x defined in file 
z.h". I would prefer an open source, command line driven tool. C++ support is 
an advantage. Is there such a tool other than cscope?

cscope doesn't preserve the type of tags. In hostapd for example there are more than 900 references to the tag "ifname". However, I'm only interested in the ifname field of a specific struct. cscope can't filter tags according to type.

Comment: Remove declaration of y field in z.h, then recompile.

Comment: Very cool. I'll see the references in the compile errors.

Comment: If you like it, I put my comment as an answer.

Comment: My answer would have been to use `cscope`. If you don't want to use cscope, it would help to explain why. Otherwise you risk getting answers about tools similar to cscope.

Comment: I've used `Elsa` as such a tool, but of course there is no ready to use query language, you have to code your searches in C++. Another, more recent option is `Clang` (either `libclang`, or clang with xml output, if you grab an older version).

Comment: @sleske: Edited answer to address comment

Comment: References: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239722/ast-from-c-code, http://scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/sources/elsa/, http://clang.llvm.org/

Answer (score 3):

Your query can be answered with your compiler:

Remove declaration of y field in z.h, then recompile.

Comment: That will usually only pick up the *first* reference per file, not all of them.

Comment: @DeadMG - It may depends on the compiler. My gcc reports every `error: structure has no member named 'y'` reference.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Mozilla DXR](https://wiki.mozilla.org/DXR) with C++ code for tasks like that. It relies on the clang platform to record code while compiling. It is a little work to setup correctly, but well worth it.

Comment: Not what I had hoped for but good information, I'll up-vote later, tnx.